# Definite article or zero article

Tags: articles, definite-article

Can you please explain which one is suitable?

> Did you watch **the** football yesterday?

Or

> Did you watch football yesterday?

I think definite article(the) is suitable here because this is specific not a general thing

Answer (score 2):

> Did you watch *the* football yesterday?

This sentence means:

> Did you keep your eyes on the football yesterday (to make sure that it wasn't stolen).

In other words, it's talking about the *object* the football—the oval thing that you throw to somebody else.

---

If you're talking about what you see on TV, you can use either:

> Did you watch football yesterday?

Or:

> Did you watch *the* football ***game*** yesterday?

Comment: If more than one match was televised yesterday, and we don't care which match you watched, we might also say: _Did you watch **a** football game yesterday?_